# drag one div to another and change size of that other div when i am over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have 3 small divs that are used to store appointment. That all work. I just want to make when I drag div with appointment to those small divs for store to change size of those small divs. I have success when i do mouse over and out but when I drag another div it doesn't work. 
Does anybody have clue what to do.

Comment: i just need code that enable resize of divs when i drag something over. I tryed with onmouseover and onmouseout and it work when i am not dragging nothing but with item that I drag it doesn't react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is the `droppable` jQuery UI library, and more specifically the `hoverClass` property.

The following is taken directly from the [jQuery UI Droppable Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#accepted-elements)

```
$("#draggable, #draggable-nonvalid" ).draggable();
$("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
            .find( "p" )
                .html( "Dropped!" );
    }
});
```